# How to get the 'countryCode' Attribute from Active Directory with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, active-directory, ldap

I am using activedirectory package to retrieve the User's information. I need to get some more details like 'countryCode, company, employeeID, etc'.

Below is the Code, what I have been used.

```
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
var ad = new ActiveDirectory('ldap://mydomain.com', 'dc=mydomain, dc=com', 'sample@mydomain.com', 'sample');
var query = 'cn=jem';
ad.findUsers(query, true, function(err, users) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
    return;
  }

  if ((! users) || (users.length == 0)) console.log('No users found.');
  else {
    console.log('findUsers: '+JSON.stringify(users));
  }
});
```

And what I get is

```
[
   {
      "dn": "CN=jem,OU=NorthWall,DC=mydomain,DC=com",
      "userPrincipalName": "jem@mydomain.com",
      "sAMAccountName": "jem",
      "whenCreated": "20160315093421.0Z",
      "pwdLastSet": "131123123123467132",
      "userAccountControl": "66048",
      "givenName": "jem",
      "cn": "jem",
      "displayName": "jem",
      "groups": []
   }
]
```

I would like to get  'countryCode, company, employeeID' attributes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory#findUsers), you can specify options for your search, including an `attributes` property where you can specify the attributes you want returned.

But..... it also says that the `attributes` property "Defaults to the empty set, which means all attributes". So you should already be getting all attributes that have values (note that AD only ever returns the attributes that have values).

Does that account have any of those other attributes set?

Comment: thanks for your quick response, I can get all the custom attributes by adding the below key set.

Comment: var ad = new ActiveDirectory({ url: 'ldap://dc.domain.com',
                               baseDN: 'dc=domain,dc=com',
                               username: 'username@domain.com',
                               password: 'password',
                               attributes: {
                                 user: [ 'myCustomAttribute', 'mail', 'userPrinicipalName' ],
                                 group: [ 'anotherCustomAttribute', 'objectCategory' ]
                               }
                              });